# How to use float values in libGDX

Tags: android, libgdx

LibGDX is using float input values for some methods but I really don't get How I can set these values. For example;

```
Sprite sprite = new Sprite();
sprite.setSize(0.9f, 0.4f);
```

I don't think these values represents pixels. Is there any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The size is in whatever world units you have decided to use in your game. This is dependent on how you set up your camera. If you are using an orthographic camera, and you set it up using its `setToOrtho` method, then whatever width and height you used in the method is how many world units wide and tall is viewable on the screen.

For example, if you did `orthocam.setToOrtho(false, 480, 800)`, then your game is set up where world units are scaled to match 480 units to the width of the screen. If you happened to use your actual screen's pixel dimensions in this camera method, then the units would be the same as pixels.

Answer (score 0):

Thoose values represents how much of the original texture size you want to put.

1 is 100%, 0.9 90%, etc.

So

```
sprite.setSize(0.9f, 0.4f);
```

This will make the sprite texture width 90% of its original width and 40% of its original height.

I recommend using just one float value, so you don't loose the aspect ratio.

```
sprite.setSize(2f); // this will make the sprite twice larger.
```